# SpringBoot Rest API Get Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building REST API using SpringBoot, this REST API accept more than one data from consumer like e.g. empId, empName, empDept. In my current code I am using `@RequestParam` annotation for accessing the query parameter values from the request. But I see we can also use the `@PathVariable` to get the data from placeholder of URI.

Wanted to know what is the best practice to get the multiple input request using `@PathVariable` `@RequestParam` OR something else?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this. In case you have a list of users:

```
GET /users (here it lists all your users)
```

It might happen for you to click on one user to access his details:

```
GET /users/{id}
```

This `{id}` you use as a `@PathVariable`

You might want to use a `@RequestParam` to filter users:

```
GET /users?name=tst&age=21
```

And your GET /users have these requests param for you to filter:

```
@RequestParam(value ="name")
@RequestParam(value ="age")
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, @PathVariable used in a case such as "getByAnything", for example, `getUserById` and one Url can have only one placeholder variable(desirable).
If your API has more than one variable your choice is @RequestParam.